# Can I get the "Flight Specialist" achievement using Prospero's ability?

Tags: into-the-breach

If I level up Prospero and gain +1 reactor, can I then start a new timeline with a customised squad and use his flight ability to gain the "Flight Specialist" achievement if I power it before the first fight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NO.**

I tested this with a squad containing the Swap Mech, the Nano Mech, and Prospero piloting the Combat Mech.

I powered up flight before the first fight, beat the game after the first two islands, and did not get the achievement.

Comment: Aww. Such a pity. Particularly given that if you start to google "into the breach flight", the second autocomplete option is "into the breach flight specialist prospero"... in other words, since lots of other people would love to do this!